# How to check for accidentally redefining a function name in R

Tags: r

I'm writing some fairly involved R code spread across multiple files and collected together into a package. A problem I've run into on occasion is that I will define a utility function in one file that has the same name as another utility function defined in another file. One of the two definitions gets replaced, leading to unintended behavior. Is there any sort of tool to check for this kind of accidental redefinition? Something that would check that no two top-level assignments `foo <- ...` in the package assign to the same name?

Comment: I would think `R CMD CHECK` will let you know if you have two definitions of the same function in your package. Alternatively, it's often recommended that each function `foo` in a package should be saved in its own file `foo.r`, which would also take care of the problem.

Comment: This actually came up in a context where I did run CHECK, but it didn't catch the fact that I had two function definitions with the same name. Also, I tend to organize my code as a large collection of smaller functions instead of a few monster functions. Currently my package has nearly 250 function definitions, only a few of which are exported. This makes it impractical to put every function in its own file.

Comment: At that point it sounds like your package is too big to manage. Maybe it should be split into smaller packages? Having small functions is of course preferred to having monsters, but even very complicated packages still follow one-function-per-file more-or-less. It's also common to put small utility functions in one place. [ggplot2, for example](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/tree/master/R) has about 170 separate R files, including a `utils.r` that has about 30 small utility functions in it.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the right way to do this is to use packages. Packages give functions their own namespaces automatically, plus they make it very easy to reuse and share code. If you're using RStudio, you can create one with very little effort from the New Project menu.

However, if you can't use packages or namespaces for some reason, there's still a way to do what you want: you can lock a variable (including a function) so that it's not possible to overwrite it.

```
> pin <- 11
> lockBinding("pin", .GlobalEnv)
> pin <- 12
Error: cannot change value of locked binding for 'pin'
```

See [Binding and Environment Locking](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/bindenv.html) for details.

Comment: I am using packages; this problem arose in the context of developing an R package that currently has 17 source files. It may make sense to split this package into multiple packages, but even with a smaller code base the problem can arise.